Strange increasing in $R^2$ when MAE and RMSE worsened for OLS
I am currently working on my thesis, which involves using machine learning to predict non-stationary and seasonal time series. I am encountering some results that I cannot explain.
While I cannot go into detail about my data, it is panel data consisting of 707 different individuals. Each individual represents a time series with an hourly frequency, and I have 3 years of observations for each. I use MSTL to decompose each time series into components that are more suitable for the machine learning methods I am applying, namely OLS and Random Forest. My study focuses on forecasting the remainder component of the decomposed time series. To address heterogeneity, I forecast each individual separately instead of using a pooling method. Additionally, to handle autocorrelation, I employ a rolling window approach with a static window size of one year. Each time the rolling window advances, the model (OLS or RF) is retrained, and we then predict $m$ steps ahead. This setup implies that a lower $m$ results in a higher retraining frequency.
When i look at the MAE, RMSE and $R^2$ of each forecast of all 707 individuals across different retraining frequencies:

the x-axis labels refers to $m$, meaning "1 steps" means $m=1$ (retraining every time step).
When examining the MAE, RMSE, and $R^2$ for each forecast of all 707 individuals across different retraining frequencies, we observe the expected behavior: as the retraining frequency increases, the size of the errors decreases. We would reasonably expect similar behavior from Random Forest; here are the metrics for RF as well:

The retraining frequency positively impacts the size of the errors once again.
Now, my question concerns the behavior of $R^2$, but only for OLS:


As shown in the two plots above, when the retraining frequency decreases (meaning more time steps are forecasted per roll of the window), the $R^2$ increases, both for the median and across all individuals, as evident from the boxplots. However, this phenomenon occurs only with OLS; with Random Forest, the $R^2$ behaves as one would expect.
Does anyone have a good explanation for this different behavior in $R^2$ observed only with OLS?
EDIT:
i have written the code in R, this is the function i have made for calculating the metrics, and the exact same function i have used for both OLS and RF:
calculate_metrics <- function(R_t, R_hat_t, individual) {
  # Ensure the inputs are numeric vectors and individual is a dataframe
  if (!is.numeric(R_t) || !is.numeric(R_hat_t)) {
    stop("Both R_t and R_hat_t need to be numeric vectors.")
  }
  if (!is.data.frame(individual)) {
    stop("individual should be a dataframe.")
  }
  
  # Extract 'elvarme' and 'zip_code' values
  elvarme_value <- unique(individual$elvarme)
  zip_code_value <- unique(individual$zip_code)
  
  # Check if there is exactly one unique value for each
  if (length(elvarme_value) != 1 || length(zip_code_value) != 1) {
    stop("elvarme and zip_code should have exactly one unique value in the dataset.")
  }
  
  # Calculate metrics
  mae <- mean(abs(R_t - R_hat_t), na.rm = TRUE)
  rmse <- sqrt(mean((R_t - R_hat_t)^2, na.rm = TRUE))
  mape <- mean(abs((R_t - R_hat_t) / R_t), na.rm = TRUE) * 100
  r_squared <- ifelse(all(R_t == R_hat_t), 1, summary(lm(R_t ~ R_hat_t))$r.squared)
  
  # Create a data frame to hold the metrics and values
  metrics_table <- data.frame(
    elvarme = elvarme_value,
    zip_code = zip_code_value,
    MAE = mae,
    RMSE = rmse,
    MAPE = mape,
    R_squared = r_squared
  )
  
  # Return the metrics table
  return(metrics_table)


Are you sure $R^2$ is being calculated correctly for OLS? (1) If you are writing your own code to calculate it, check for typos. (2) If it's reported by your software, double-check whether the output you are using is the correct one.

Also, please say how $R^2$ is being calculated, either in your code or in the package you use. Not every calculation has the same relationship with MSE.

@civilstat please see the edit.

@Dave please see the edit.

What is the ifelse doing?

@Dave The ifelse function is used in the calculation of $R2$ to handle a specific edge case where all observed values $R_t$​ are exactly equal to the predicted values $\hat{R_t}$​. so just making sure that in this case the value of $R^2$ is 1.

I think I see what happened. You regress the true values on the predictions, meaning that your linear regression $R^2$ value is equal to the squared Pearson correlation between the true and predicted values, rather than being based on the mean squared error of the model predictions. This is because $\left(\text{corr}\left(x, y\right)\right)^2=\left(\text{corr}\left(ax+b, cy+d\right)\right)^2$ for $a,b\ne0$ and $b,d\in\mathbb R$. Squaring Pearson correlation misses multiple ways by which the predictions differ from the observed values [1, 2]. When you fit the model in an OLS linear model and look at in-sample data, squared Pearson correlation agrees with other common definitions of $R^2$, but this only holds in special cases.
If you calculate according to $
R^2=1-\left(\dfrac{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\hat y_i
\right)^2
}{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\bar y
\right)^2
}\right)
$, you calculation should be more related to the mean squared error of the model predictions. Do be careful to pay attention to the denominator. If you change the denominator, you can wind up with MSE and $R^2$ moving in the same direction (both increase or both decrease).
The MLmetrics::R2_Score function will calculate this way, with the caveat that out-of-sample $R^2$ is not quite calculated the way I think it should be (or that I believe is most valuable).
